# How to make sure angular reactive form setValue/patchvalue is complete

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

if I set a form value like bellow

```
this.loadBasicForm.setValue({
       loadDirection,
       loadSubDirection,
       multiPointType,
       truckLoadType
});
```

I have to use setTimeout to make sure that the value is updated.

```
setTimeout(() => {
 //do some other action with the changed values.
}
```

Is there a better way to do this, other than using setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

### Angular FormArray tracks the value and validity state of an array of FormControl, FormGroup or FormArray instances. setValue() and patchValue() are the methods of FormArray class.

setValue(): Sets the value of the FormArray. We need to pass an array that must match the structure of the control. If our array does not match the structure of the control, setValue() will throw error.

### So, if you don't encounter any problem setValue() than the execution was done.

patchValue(): Patches the value of FormArray. We need to pass an array that should match the structure of the control. If the array that we pass, does not match the structure of the control completely, then patchValue() will patch only those fields which are matching with the structure of the control and rest will be as it is.

### So,if your fields are not matching, it's the issue which you have made.